# Linq on string array

Tags: c#, linq

```
string[] listOne = new string[] { "dog", "cat", "car", "apple"};
string[] listTwo = new string[] { "car", "apple"};
```

What I need is to order `listOne` by the order of items in `listTwo`(if present). So the new list would be in this order:

> "car", "apple", "dog", "cat"

Comment: You don't need linq. Just loop through second list and if the value there is matched by the first list add that value to the sorted list and remove it from the source list. Then add all remaining elements in the source list to the sorted list.

Comment: what you recommend is exactly linq good at.

Answer (score 3):

You can use extension method **Union()**

```
var result = listTwo.Union<string>(listOne);
```

Comment: Where is the intersection the op asked?

Comment: Union extension method would be the same as Union two sets in terms of mathematic. Union set would consists of intersection. The result is the same.

Comment: The explicit of the type of generics can be omitted: `listTwo.Union(listOne)`. I guess this answer is most applicable.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = listTwo.Union(listOne);
```

OR

```
var result =listTwo.Intersect(listOne).Concat(listOne.Except(listTwo));
var result = listTwo.Where(listOne.Contains).Concat(listOne.Except(listTwo));
```

First answer posted has bug with `listTwo` item order, please neglect below answer

```
var result = listOne.OrderBy(i => !listTwo.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

result

```
"car", "apple", "dog", "cat"
```

Comment: Would this work if listTwo was : { "apple", "car" } wouldn't it return the items in the same order as they appear in listOne?

Comment: A combination of your approach and mine would solve the question I raised: var result = listOne.OrderBy(i => !listTwo.Contains(i)).ThenBy(i => Array.IndexOf(listTwo,i)).ToList(); an probably look a lot simpler than my approach.

Comment: @Squid: If `listTwo` was `{ "apple", "car" }`, the code in this answer outputs an array of `{ "car", "apple", "dog", "cat" }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sub1 = listOne.Intersect(listTwo).ToList();
var sub2 = listOne.Except(listTwo); 
sub1.AddRange(sub2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using arrays, most of the use of linq, will create a new instance of some kind of `IEnumerable`, for example, `ToList` or `ToArray`.

Thus I'd suggest that to use `Array.Sort` with [Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/tfakywbh.aspx):

```
string[] listOne=new string[] { "dog", "cat", "car", "apple" };
string[] listTwo=new string[] { "car", "apple" };

Comparison<String> comparison=
    (x, y) => {
        if(!listTwo.Contains(x)||!listTwo.Contains(y))
            return 0;
        else {
            var indexOfX=Array.IndexOf(listTwo, x);
            var indexOfY=Array.IndexOf(listTwo, y);
            return indexOfX.CompareTo(indexOfY);
        }
    };

Array.Sort(listOne, comparison);
```

It would be sorted with [quick sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) internally, it's an [in-place algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).

Comment: I believe the focus here was to get something simple for the OP

Comment: @Marco: ah .. is this not simple .. ?

Comment: @Marco: But the currently highest voted answer outputs with an incorrect result if the order in `listTwo` changes ..

Comment: But that is what the OP what, otherwise we would have said a ordered list two.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I have a feeling it could be done better:

```
var result=
    from item in listOne
    let existsInListTwo=listTwo.Contains(item)
    let positionInListTwo=Array.IndexOf(listTwo, item)
    orderby !existsInListTwo, positionInListTwo
    select new {
        Item=item,
        position=positionInListTwo,
        exists=existsInListTwo
    };
```

Edit: Using a combination of this and Damith's approach this is a little more readable:

```
var result=
    listOne.OrderBy(i => !listTwo.Contains(i))
           .ThenBy(i => Array.IndexOf(listTwo, i))
           .ToList();
```

Comment: changing to let existsInListTwo = (positionInListTwo != -1) would avoid a second enumeration of listTwo.

Comment: It is not better than the existing options provided, it is actually actually the worst option and the most complicated to read.

Comment: Marco - but to my mind it is the only one that solves the question OP asked.  If you were to change the order of the items in listTwo, none of the other answers would order results in the order they appear in listTwo, they simply bubble results that are in listTwo to the top.

Comment: But is the least readable, and that is important as well and are you sure the OP asked that; I can't understand the question myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = listOne.Union(listTwo)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(i => !listTwo.Contains(i));
```